# SASS wrap mixin to add extra argument

Tags: sass

I am working with a mixin called `button` with the following signature:

```
@mixin button($expand: false,
              $background: $button-background,
              $background-hover: $button-background-hover,
              $color: $button-color, $style: solid)
```

I would like to create a mixin to wrap this one called `sized-button`, that takes an additional parameter to indicate the size of the button based on a `$button-sizes` map.

The map looks like this:

```
$button-sizes: (
    tiny: 0.6rem,
    small: 0.75rem,
    default: 0.9rem,
    large: 1.25rem,
);
```

I was hoping to use variable arguments so that I don't have to redefine the arguments for the `button` mixin. For example, this was my first attempt:

```
@mixin sized-button($size: default, $buttonArgs...) {
  @if (map-has-key($button-sizes, $size)) {
    @include button($buttonArgs);
    font-size: map-get($button-sizes, $size);
  }
  @else {
   @warn "Invalid button size";
  }
}
```

However, doing this does not seem to work. For example, if I pass one of the `button` arguments to the `sized-button` mixin, I get an error:

```
@include sized-button($size: large, $expand: true);
Mixin sized-button has no parameter named $expand
```

Is it possible to do what I'm trying to do?